# Out of tropolone and tropone, which is more soluble in water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility, hydrogen-bond, physical-organic-chemistry

According to me tropolone has intramolecular H-bonding, so extent of H-bonding with water will decrease and thus, will be less soluble.

[Tropone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropone) (Cyclohepta-2,4,6-trien-1-one):

[image]

[Tropolone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropolone) (2-hydroxytropone):

[image]

Comment: The fact that trololone can *do* strong hydrogen bonding suggests to me it will be *more* soluble in water. tropone can't do strong hydrogen bonding (no -OH group). So what are you comparing tropolone to? 3-hyroxytropone might be more soluble than the 2-hydroxy isomer, but on what basis can you compare solubility to something which isn't an isomer at all and doesn't have *any* hydrogen bonding?

Comment: For the [OSISIS property explorer](https://openmolecules.org/propertyexplorer/applet.html), tropone yields a predicted value of cLogS of -1.39, tropolone of -1.32.  Thus, *for the trained model implemented* ([theory](https://openmolecules.org/properties/properties.html), 2k compounds, pH 7.5, 25 C).  Of course, it is a model.

Answer (score 5):

The presence of internal hydrogen bonding does not automatically mean lower water solubility. The water solubility difference between fumaric and maleic acid provides a good example.

Maleic acid (the Z-isomer) is capable of an internal hydrogen bond between the two carboxylic acid functional groups.

[image]

Fumaric acid (the E-isomer) is not capable of internal hydrogen bonding.
[image]

Maleic acid is about 100 times more soluble in water than fumaric acid.

- Maleic acid: 480 g/L
- Fumaric acid: 4.9 g/L

From these data, it is clear that the internal hydrogen bond is not an impediment to water solubility. Maleic acid is more soluble because it is more polar with the polar functional groups on the same side of the molecule. Fumaric acid is less soluble because it is less polar. The two polar functional groups are on opposite sides so the individual bond dipoles cancel.

This example may not extend to the comparison of tropone and tropolone, which are not isomers. Having reliable water solubility data for both compounds would provide useful information, but I was unable to find them.

Comment: Tropolone appears to have a solubility of about 5 g per L, but I couldn't find data for tropone, Thus, I made an analogy. Of course, data on the specific compounds will trump a generalization.

Comment: So in the end, which is more soluble?

Comment: I feel that this doesn't really answer the OP's question, it's more of an interesting tangent.

Comment: @BenNorris *“Maleic acid is ten times more soluble in water than fumaric acid.

Maleic acid: 480 g/L
Fumaric acid: 4.9 g/L“* Either the statement or the data has been given wrong by mistake, I suppose. Also, I agree with ShoubhikRMaiti that this really doesn’t answer the question OP has posed, though it is a important piece of information.

Comment: logP data is available from chemspider. It agrees with the trend described by the OP, if not proof that the suggested mechanism is correct. A better argument might be to compare structural isomers of tropolone (eg 2- versus 3-hydroxytropone).

Comment: @BuckThorn But isn't logP, regardless if computed / predicted, or based on an *in virto* experiment, about *partition* only?  It is not so evident (for me) how you relate a logP (octanol / water) of compound x into solubility of compound x in water if logP of x and molar mass of x are the only properties known in first hand.

Comment: @Buttonwood interestingly this post surfaced, which addresses your point: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/153155/looking-for-caffeine-partition-coefficients  In retrospect I think my previous comment was not entirely correct. Need to think a little more about this.

Comment: @BuckThorn Like there are logP and clogP, there are cLogS about predicted solubility, too (example [theory](https://openmolecules.org/properties/properties.html) / [implementation](https://openmolecules.org/propertyexplorer/applet.html)).  Probably this is easier if the molecules don't contain groups easy to ionize.

Comment: @BuckThorn For curiosity, I used this tool equally on both isomers.  But the implemented model seems to posess some limitations, because the predicted data of cLogS are -0.25 (maleic acid), and -0.25 (fumaric acid).

Comment: @Buttonwood thanks for the links. Hmm, that is an impressively bad prediction of relative solubility, I wonder why. I think the approach of comparing solubility and partition coefficients might work better for different substituted tropones. Also, many predictive tools are based on ML algorithms, and the question was looking for a mechanistic explanation, so even a very accurate prediction is of little use if it doesn't provide insight (in this context).

Comment: @BuckThorn I agree. Like [this work](https://jcheminf.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13321-018-0316-5) mentioned in one of the answers [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/153155/looking-for-caffeine-partition-coefficients), a simple click-and-use-the-results of programs without knowledge what algorithm and implementation may be dangerous; and chemistry is no exception to this (e.g.[EuSpRIG](http://www.eusprig.org/)).